# Store variables on netty TCP Connection

Tags: java, netty

I need to store an Object for later usage on a TCP connection on NETTY. After user login, some variables need to be stored on this user connection.

What's the proper way to do it? I tried storing some variables on ChannelHandler Context(), but this is deprecated:

```
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
{
    ctx.attr(attrObj).set(new Session(ctx));
}
```

Then I tried storing on channel:

```
public void channelRegistered(ChannelHandlerContext ctx)
{
    ctx.channel().attr(attrObj).set(new Session(ctx));
}
```

The object was shared with all TCP Sessions, so no success.

How can I set my Session() object on this specific TCP user connection, so all next messages from this user, can retrieve this data easily?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `ctx.channel().attr(attrObj).set(...)` as you did. Each channel has different attributes and so it is per connection. If there are multiple sessions per TCP connection you will need to put it in a map that is stored as attribute on the `Channel`.

Comment: You are right, it works! =| I think I found my problem, thanks!